# Django and action attribute of form elements

Tags: django

HTML5 stipulates that action attribute of the form element "must have a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces" 
(https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-action).

Could you help me understand why the documentation of Django always suggests this: 
{% csrf_token %}

Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Leaving action="" seems to be error prone.

So, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have right. Empty action attribute is inconsistent with HTML5 Standard but engines browsers deal with this.
2. Protection using CSRF is good practice. CSRF can protect againts bots.

Comment: So, can I use empty action or not? This is the question.

Comment: As Marcin says, in practice browsers will be able to handle `action=""` just fine. You can either leave it as it is, change it to the url e.g. `action="/contact/"`,  or remove the action completely.